# Availability of servers used by the API osmdroid

Tags: android, server, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Here I see the information that the API uses dedicated servers:

> Several libraries make it easy for Android developers to incorporate OpenStreetMap in Their own applications, Whether as a static map image, a fully interactive map, or more sophisticated uses like geocoding and routing. **Another benefit of using These libraries is que They respect OpenStreetMap's tile usage policy by fetching tiles and other resources from dedicated servers instead of OpenStreetMap's donated servers.**
>
> (And then the API osmdroid appears in the list)
>
> Wiki link: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android

That's right?
Does anyone know the availability of the servers used by the API osmdroid?

(osmdroid API link https://github.com/osmdroid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend on the tile provider you choose. According to [TileSourceFactory.java](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/44408833ca2c16c5cf35b8681e9fa02ef3099263/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/tilesource/TileSourceFactory.java) there are various provider available, *including* the official OSM server which have a very strict [tile usage policy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy).

Of course you can use any [alternative tile provider](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy#Alternative_OpenStreetMap_Tile_Providers) you want, including your own one.